# Error when trying to export table to a csv file (errcode: 2)

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm trying to export my table to a .csv file. The query (mysql) is:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEMP_FINAL
INTO OUTFILE '/home/test/TEMP_FINAL.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I get the following error:

"Can't create/write to file '/home/test/TEMP_FINAL.csv' (Errcode: 2)

The directory "test" has permission to write and I`m using Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.

What is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql program does not have access to a user's directory. Change the outfile to somewhere like `/tmp/` and move the file later.

Comment: Outfiles created by mysql is saved inside /var/lib/mysql/<database_concerned>. But that directory requires sudo access. You can do `SELECT *
FROM TEMP_FINAL
INTO OUTFILE 'TEMP_FINAL.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';` Then `sudo su` (hoping that you know what it means). Now you can `cd` into `var/lib/mysql/<concerned_dbname>` and pick out your `TEMP_FINAL.csv`. Accept the answer if it works for you.